# How to change tab on tabbar if Future List returns empty

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a TabBar with 2 tabs (services and coaches). I populate this tabs with 2 Future Lists (using FutureBuilders on each tab). What I want to do is: when the first Future completes and the List is empty,I want the tabbar animates to the second tab (tab with index 1). How can I achieve this?

```
final List<Widget> _tabs = [
const Tab(text: 'Servicios'),
const Tab(text: 'Profesionales'), 
];

TabBar(
  isScrollable: false,
  controller: _tabController,
  tabs: _tabs,
),

TabBarView(
  controller: _tabController,
  children: [
     // TAB 0
     FutureBuilder<List<ServiceCardCommonWidget>>(
       future: widget.futureServices,
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
         // if snapshot.data.isEmpty I want to animate to the tab with index 1
       } 
     ),
     // TAB 1
     FutureBuilder<List<CoachCardCommonWidget>>(
        future: widget.futureCoaches,
        builder: (context, snapshot) { 
           // Content of Tab 1  
        },
    ),
],
```

),

Comment: You wrote it right in your question: animateTo is the name of controller's function you want to use. However you will need to check that the futures return first. The way you are doing it now will not work most likely.

Comment: The problem that I'm getting if I call the animateTo inside the builder of FutureBuilder is "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build."

Comment: You should watch the video [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) pay attention to the connection states at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not animate inside the build method. As mentioned in docs,

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
> `State.initState`, `State.didUpdateWidget`, or
> `State.didChangeDependencies`. It must not be created during the
> `State.build` or `StatelessWidget.build` method call when constructing the
> `FutureBuilder`. If the future is created at the same time as the
> `FutureBuilder`, then every time the `FutureBuilder`'s parent is rebuilt,
> the asynchronous task will be restarted.

You can check for the result of Future inside `initState` and animate to the desired Tab.

```
 final List<Widget> _tabs = [
    const Tab(text: 'Servicios'),
    const Tab(text: 'Profesionales'),
  ];

  late Future<List<String>> getServices;
  late Future<List<String>> getProfessions;

  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: _tabs.length, vsync: this);

    getServices = Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      final r = math.Random().nextBool();
      return r ? ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'] : [];
    })
      ..then((value) => value.isEmpty ? _tabController.animateTo(1) : null);

    getProfessions =
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => ['P1', 'P2', 'P3']);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Soliev! Thanks for the answer! Yep, that did for me! Thanks!